# How does colormap work

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure, colormap

I can't understand how does `colormap` work and how is it used.

I am completing a programming assignment, where I am provided with some code in which `colormap` is used, however I can't understand what exactly does it accomplish.

Here is a condensed code:

```
colormap(gray);
h = imagesc(display_array, [-1 1]);
```

Here `display_array` contains the pixel intensities of a grayscale image.

I read [this](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#buq1hym) article and slightly understood that `colormap` is a matrix with any number of rows and `3` columns with values between`0` and `1`.

I checked the values of the pixel intensities in my grayscale image and found values between `-1` and `2`. Now I can't understand how `mapping` occurs between this image and the `colormap` as mentioned in the above article. Just a high level idea of how this happens would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When displaying an image, it is necessary to establish a relationship between data *values* and the color of the pixels on the screen that correspond to those values. This is the purpose of the colormap. It literally *maps* a data value to a *color*.

How this mapping occurs depends upon the color limits of the axes. The color limits indicate which value of your data to map to the first value in the colormap and which to map to the last value in the colormap. You can adjust these limits for a given `axes` via the [`CLim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_CLim) property or via the [`caxis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) function.

By default [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) (a scaled image) will set the color limits such that the biggest value of your data is used for the upper color limit and the smallest value is used for the lower color limit. This is the equivalent of

```
set(gca, 'CLim', [min(display_array(:)), max(display_array(:))])
```

In the case of the `grey` colormap, the first value is black and the last value is white meaning that any values less than or equal to the lower color limit will be shown as black, any values greater than or equal to the upper color limit will be shown as white and everything in between will be a shade of gray proportional to their value.

You can use the `colormap` function to specify any colormap that you want. `grey` is just a built-in colormap for grayscale images. The format of the colormap is that each row contains three elements (red, green, blue) and the lower color limit is mapped to the first entry, the upper color limit is mapped to the last and data is mapped linearly to all colors that may appear in between the two.

In the example that you have shown, however, you have specified the color limits [as the second input argument to `imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html#inputarg_clims) and manually forced them to be `[-1 1]`. This means that now -1 is mapped to the first value in the colormap (black) and `1` is mapped to the last (white). Since you have values larger than 1, all of these values will be forced to be white since the upper color limit is 1.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My image does have values between `-1` and `0`, as stated in the question, but your misinterpretation helped me understand it even better.

Comment: I just can't understand one thing you wrote:
`You can adjust these limits for a given axes`, which axes are we talking about?

Comment: @shiva The axes that contains the image.